# Converting Connection string to SQLOLEDB

Tags: asp-classic, ado

Connection Code:

```
set conx = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
conx.Open Application("connectionString")

set cmdx = server.CreateObject("ADODB.command")
cmdx.ActiveConnection = conx
cmdx.CommandText = "dbo.sproc"
cmdx.CommandType = &H0004

set rsx = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsx.open cmdx

resarray = rsx.getrows
```

This connection string works:

```
connectionString = "DRIVER=SQL Server;UID=User;Address=000.000.000.000;Network=DBMSSOCN;DATABASE=Database;SERVER=server;Password=password;"
```

This doesn't...

```
connectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=000.000.000.000;UID=User;Address=000.000.000.000;Network=DBMSSOCN;DATABASE=Database;SERVER=server;Password=password;"
```

The error I get is:

```
ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'

Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a punt here, but the way OLEDB drivers handle Row count informationals differs from ODBC.

I very much suspect that if you add SET NOCOUNT ON at the top of the Stored Procedure the problem will go away.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a permissions problem in the database!

Comment: It's the same database, just a different way of reaching it.